# Simple elevator-like animation android

Tags: java, android, animation

```
 private void moveViewToScreenCenter(final ImageView img, int x) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    img.animate()
            .translationX(0)
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    enableAll();
                    showDialog();
                }
            })
            .translationY(-x * dm.heightPixels / 6)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
            .setStartDelay(0);
}

public void showDialog()
{
    final CharSequence[] items = {"0", "1", "2","3","4","5"};

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("which floor is your destination");

    alertDialogBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if (items[item].equals("0")) {

                moveViewToScreen(img, 0);
            } else if (items[item].equals("1")) {

                moveViewToScreen(img, 1);
            } else if (items[item].equals("2")) {

                moveViewToScreen(img, 2);
            } else if (items[item].equals("3")) {

                moveViewToScreen(img, 3);
            } else if (items[item].equals("4")) {

                moveViewToScreen(img,4);
            }else if (items[item].equals("5")) {

                moveViewToScreen(img,5);
            }

            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder.show();

}

private void moveViewToScreen(final ImageView img, int x) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    img.animate()
            .translationX(0)
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    enableAll();

                }
            })
            .translationY(-x * dm.heightPixels / 6)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
            .setStartDelay(0);
}
```

Buttons are disabled (disableALL()) during animation but animation seems fast between far floors and slow between consecutive ones . i'm still new to android and simple animation stuff like this

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. Please include a description of your code before your code, so that reviewers may see that short description when browsing.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Unfortunately I personally [do not consider this a good question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/checklist-for-how-to-write-a-good-code-review-question/6429#6429) (In particular, see the "On-topic", "Screenshot" and "Motivation" sections, and work on your Description). With a few changes to your question, you can make it much more clearer and more interesting for reviewers. I am hoping to give you an upvote soon.

Comment: About the slow movement: The duration is *always* 2 seconds, so you need to scale that with the distance of your image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Janos`' advice is applying [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle to your code.  It can be extended to also cover `moveViewToScreenCenter` and `moveViewToScreen` functions, since they are almost identical:

```
private void moveViewToScreenCenter(final ImageView img, int x, boolean center) {
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    this.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    img.animate()
            .translationX(0)
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    enableAll();
                    if (center)
                       showDialog();
                }
            })
            .translationY(-x * dm.heightPixels / 6)
            .setDuration(2000)
            .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
            .setStartDelay(0);
}
```

and call this function by providing `true`/`false` to your `center` parameter.

Also, [functional scalability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalability) might be an issue: **what if you have to handle 11 eleven floors in the future? (0 -> 10)**. You will be forced make several changes to handle a simple request like this.

In order to accommodate larger values, I would dynamically define your array and not base my condition on char (which allows only one character). Something like this (not tested):

```
// place this in some generic place
List<Integer> makeSequence(int begin, int end) {
  List<Integer> ret = new ArrayList(end - begin + 1);
  for(int i = begin; i <= end; i++, ret.add(i));
  return ret;  
}

int maxFloors = 5;
List<Integer> items = makeSequence(0, 5);

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
    moveViewToScreen(img, items[item]);
    dialog.dismiss();
}
```